# SP2013 How to do vertical flyout menu in top navigation

Tags: custom-masterpage

I have a problem to get the vertical flyouts to work in SP2013, I try to do it the SP2010 way to change the DynamicDisplayLevel but no luck.. Need help on this to achieve the same functionally as we had on SP2010.

Regards
Martin

Comment: Are you editing the SharePoint:AspMenu like you need to do in SP2010?

Comment: Make sure your not using Metadata-driven navigation

Comment: It looks like a duplicate: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75036/how-to-display-drop-down-menu-top-navigation-trying-for-many-days-now/75041#75041

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you've enabled Publishing Feature for both Site Collection and Site.
2. Under Look and Feel > Click Navigation
3. Make sure Show Subsites is checked and Structured Navigation is selected for Global Navigation.
4. In your custom master page find the code

   ```
   <SharePoint:AspMenu
     ID="TopNavigationMenu"
     Runat="server"
     EnableViewState="false"
     DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
     AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
     UseSimpleRendering="true"
     UseSeparateCss="false"
     Orientation="Horizontal"
     StaticDisplayLevels="2"
     AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
     MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
     SkipLinkText="" />
   ```

Change `StaticDisplayLevels` to `1` and `MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels` to the number of dynamic levels you'd want.

Comment: Is it worked only for 3 level? How to get 4 levels? I have tried to give `StaticDisplayLevels` to `1` and `MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels` to `4` and `5`. But couldn't succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

In Sharepoint Online 2013 and O365 publishing sites, a good option these days is to combine structural nav with the no-code edit links feature. This give you the benefit of having a more complex menu structure, without sacrificing usability.

Settings > navigation to create structural navigation items.

On any page > edit links to drag and drop items under others.

Easy to follow instructions here:
https://newsignature.com/articles/no-code-global-navigation-flyout-dropdown-sharepoint-2013-online