# How to display drop down menu (top navigation) - trying for many days now

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, navigation, master-page, design-manager

I am trying to display top navigation as drop down menu just like you see in theme "seattle".

I created my own theme, then I went to "Design Manager" and then I went to "Snippets". I copied the top navigation snippet in my master page but it is showing all links as it is i.e. it is not showing in drop down format.

I thought may be because I didn't use snippet from "seattle" so I copied seattle's snippet in my master page but same problem :(

How do I show drop down like seattle so that I can modify it according to my needs? I will modify it using Firebug but first I need to display it which I am unable to to for the past many days now.

**EDIT1**

1. I have opened preview and snippet of seattle theme
2. I am just playing with values of StaticDisplayLevels and I notice that when I press "Update" button, it does change preview in "snippet"
3. But when I go back to preview page (the left side tab in screenshot) and refresh page then I don't see any change. So it looks like besides pressing "Update" button I also need to do something else?

Screenshots given below.

- Screenshot1
  [image]
- Screenshot2
  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change any attributes inside **SharePoint:AspMenu** ?

Try setting StaticDisplayLevels="3" and MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1" inside your generated HTML for the master.

Or, in the Design manager, in snippet's settings, you could set the same settings according to the sceenshot:

[image]

Comment: I did like you said but still no drop down menu. But I noticed one thing. I made the changes, Clicked on "Update" button, then copied that code again and pasted it in my master page. Then after that when I went to snippet again, I saw that the changes I made have been reverted. So basically StaticDisplayLevels changes back to "2" from "3" and MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels changes back to "0" from "1"

Comment: That's weird. So, I think the problem is somewhere there. What if you try to temporary remove the association between .master and .html by deselecting the check box in .html's file properties?(http://ge.tt/1PyFAyo/v/0). Then inside .master try chaning the same attributes that are not saved.

Comment: Ok I did a complete reinstall of Windows Server, SQL Server and SharePoint. Now when I change values then I can see changes but still something is missing. Please check my EDIT1 above in which I have explained in detail. Looks like my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: I am able to display drop down menu. This is how I did, make changes in snippet, press Update button, copy new code, check out your master page and open it in SD, paste new code, save page or publish it, refresh page in browser and now you will see changes. Plus I also found out that there is a known bug in SharePoint 2013 which won't allow you to display more than 2 levels using MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels unless you use managed navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change it within sharepoint to make it into a drop down:

http://www.helpmeonsharepoint.com/2012/08/sharepoint-2013-easier-custom.html

You need to set the global navigation to

> "Managed Navigation"

[image: managed nav]

this will change your menu to a drop down for the siblings ;)

happy coding :)

Comment: I am already using Managed Navigation and all my links are being shown in drop down in seattle. But when I apply my own theme and then copy/paste snippet where I want navigation to appear, it doesn't show in drop down format but just plain links.

Comment: are you trying to move the menu from one location to another? eg from left to far right or bottom of page?

Answer (score 0):

If your menu is still not displaying in a drop-down, make sure the AdjustForShowStartingNode = true.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using managed navigation, then you will need to create items for navigation using Site Settings -> Term Store Management Tool. This would create the items in the menu.
Also grab the navigation code from default master page files (solo.html) and put in your template. That should fix drop downs for global navigation.

Answer (score 0):

> Under Customizations - Top Navigation (AspMenu)
>
> > Under Important - Set **StaticDisplayLevels** = 2
> >
> > Under Behavior - 
> >     Set **MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels** = 3

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5.aspx

The static view (StaticDisplayLevels) allows you to set the static (always appearing items).

The Dynamic view (MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels) allows the items to be visible once you hover into it.

My settings for it would be to set static to 2 and dynamic to 3.

But everything has to depend on your navigation settings and your subsites and pages.