# How to add sublevel in quick launch

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, master-page, quick-launch

I'd like adding a sub level in my quick launch.
I modified my master page

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap" UseSimpleRendering="true" UseSeparateCss="false" Orientation="Vertical" StaticDisplayLevels="3" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1" SkipLinkText="" CssClass="s4-ql" />
```

I do an `iisreset` but if i go to the quick launch, i can't add navigation link in a new sub heading 
I try this in powershell without success

```
    $web = get-spweb http://monurl
$ql = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch
$heading = $ql | where {$_.title -eq "Lists"}
$headingNode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode("subhead", "")
$heading.Children.Add($headingNode,$heading)
    $navnode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode("Search the web with Google", "http://www.google.com", $true)
    $headingNode.Children.Add($navnode,$headingNode)
```

If i check in powershell i've correctly the children but nothing appears in quick launch

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Did you publish the masterpage as a major version after you modified it?

Comment: yes it's correctly publish and in major version

Comment: Take a look here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75036/how-to-display-drop-down-menu-top-navigation-trying-for-many-days-now

Comment: I've correctly setted value in master page but nothing change

Comment: Are there a special thing to add sub heading after setting MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels to 3?